# What type of hose bib is this?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I am trying to understand what type of hose bibb is this. Is it male or female? I don't understand where is it finishing.

I would like to understand where the pipe ends and the hose bibb starts.

[image: hose bibb with hose attached, from the side]

[image: hose bibb with hose attached, from the top]

[image: hose bibb with hose attached, from the other side]

[image: hose bibb with hose attached, with green & blue rectangles indicating portions to be identified]

[image: pipe sticking out of the wall with hands holding a hose bibb to be installed]

[image: hose bibb with orange rectangle indicating location of leak]

Comment: Looks like a regular outdoor faucet.  It is connected inside to house/building water pipes and used for outside watering.  This case a garden type hose is connected to it.

Comment: Are you asking about the part that connects to the pipe?  Because that is a compression fitting on what was a bare copper pipe coming out of the wall.  If you're asking about the hose end, that, by convention, is always male.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to understand where the pipe ending and the hose bib starting. I added one more image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hose bib that you have is connected to the wall with a compression fitting.  The parts of the fitting are shown in the image below.  Imagine the tee is your hose bib.

[image: compression fitting parts]

I assume you are trying to replace the hose bib, and that presents a few problems.  Looking at the image, the ferrule is a deformable soft brass washer that crimps onto the pipe when you tighten the fitting.  It *compresses* to seal the fitting.  That means that it won't come off, and that means that you can't remove the nut without cutting the pipe or cutting the nut.

In this case, the pipe sticking out of the wall is very short, so cutting it won't give you a lot of room to make a new connection.  I think your best bet would be to get a new hose bib with a compression fitting, but try to use the existing ferrule and nut with the new fitting.  This isn't the best practice, but with enough tightening, you might be able to get a good seal.  Unfortunately, the new piece might be a slightly different shape and you may not be able to make a good seal.

If you do have to cut off the nut and ferrule to make a clean connection, I would try to cut off the nut first and then cut the copper pipe as close to the ferrule as you can.  Every mm counts here. But, if using a new bib with the old nut and ferrule doesn't work, I would be inclined to call a plumber.  If you make a mistake that close to the wall, the repair will end up being much harder and expensive.

Comment: It is possible, in my experience, to slide the ferrule off the pipe by banging the nut against it. (Use an adjustable wrench, sized bigger than the pipe but smaller than the nut.) Maybe I've not had properly installed compression fittings, but I've been able to remove some.

Comment: @FreeMan, yea, that is possible, but this one appears to be pretty old.  It's worth a try if you're to the point where you would need to cut it off and start over to save a little pipe length.

Comment: @FreeMan and JPhi1618
Thank you so much. Just for clarification. I added one more image. I'm not sure the name for this part in orange box, but this part is leaking (you can see water in first image). I will try to fix this part first and replace washer, but not sure if I can unscrew it. I reason why I'm asking here, like for plan B, if something will go wrong with my plan of A for fixing orange box part. But I feeling I will not able unsrew it.

Comment: @Alexander that's what you should have asked about in the first place! "My hose bibb is leaking here, how do I fix it?" would make a _great_ NEW question.

Comment: @FreeMan Sure I will create another one.

Comment: @FreeMan https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/235136/my-hose-bib-is-leaking-here-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: If you get to the ferrule removal part and banging the nut doesn't work, you can **gently** hacksaw across the ferrule and then insert a flat screwdriver tip and twist to break the ferrule. Key here is to not nick the 1/2" copper at all. Don't try to cut all the way through the ferrule. (But as mentioned, re-using the old nut/ferrule will frequently work, so hopefully it doesn't come to this.)

Comment: I don't know if similar devices exist in the US, but in the UK you can buy an "olive puller" which will remove the olive and nut from the pipe cleanly.

Comment: @PeterGreen Thanks, that's great!  "Compression Sleeve Puller" seems to turn up results on Home Depot and Amazon for US versions.  I saw a few reviews on "olive pullers" saying they don't fit American pipes, so buy a made-for-America version.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it would be a "male" hose bibb, though I've never heard that term.

It "ends" at the nut on the pipe leading into the wall. If you were to put a wrench on that nut, and another on the flats (where it says `ABC` in the first pic), you could unscrew it. Of course, you'd want to remove the hose first.

Comment: I added one more image. Do you mean blue one is pipe and green one is hose bib? Is it right?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, the blue is pipe and green is hose bib.  JPhi1618 is correct that the hose bib attaches to the pipe from the house using a compression fitting.  If you were to disconnect the compression fitting as FreeMan says, the pipe would be sticking out with no fitting attached. The compression fitting is part of the hose bib in this case.  A "male" thread has threads on the outside and a "female" thread has threads on the inside.

Comment: @StephenDaddona I added one more image from the Internet. Is it the correct one? Sorry for the quality it is from youtube, but the idea I think you can see. So this is the type of connection I have, right?

Comment: Yes, @Alexander, the Blue box designates the pipe (including the nut on for the compression fitting), while the Green box designates the hose bibb. And, yes, your last "from the internet" image is what you have.

Comment: @Alexander note that most (all?) hose bibbs now come with a vacuum breaker to ensure that any water that enters the hose cannot go back into the house through the pipe. This ensures that dirt, etc. from the end of the hose doesn't get sucked up, back through the hose bibb, through the plumbing and come out your kitchen sink into your glass of drinking water or pot of spaghetti water. i.e., if you're looking to replace this bibb, you may not find one that _looks_ exactly like this however, if it has the proper threads for the compression fitting it will work just fine.

Comment: I would add that you can sometimes stop the leak you have marked with a yellow box simply by tightening that nut. Use two wrenches: put one on the nut next to the handle and the other on the nut just below it.  There is a bushing inside that you can compress a  little more by tightening that nut a little.  Maybe you will not have to replace the entire hose bib at all.

Comment: These are common on stucco type houses as you cannot really screw in the traditional bib as easy.   You will need two monkey wrenches to unscrew it as the nut on the left needs to be supported or the torque will cause the pipe to lift and possibly damage wall.