# How do I fix a hose bib that's leaking under the handle?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Could you advise? Part in orange box leaking. I feel I should try to unscrew the orange part and try to replace the washer. But I feeling it can be stoked and can't unscrew it (orange part). I would like to prepare for all possible variants and all the needed tools. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: "But I feeling it can be stoked and can't unscrew it". "can be stoked" = "might be stuck"? Have you tried unscrewing yet? You'll have to take the handle off first.

Comment: @FreeMan I did. Now I somewhere read that WD 40 to connection place for 24  hours can help me. Now I ordered WD 40. But looking for a connection I am still not sure if it will help me.

Comment: Open and maybe remove handle first to give the nut room to move.  Might need bigger wrench.

Comment: @Alexander, WD-40 is not actually a penetrating oil, and not great for unsticking things.  It works, but there are better options sold as "penetrant" or " penetrating oil" like the brand PB Blaster.

Comment: WD-40 is [a lie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil).  It was designed to [polish the Atlas missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil), and they went on a marketing frenzy trying to convince us it's good for anything else.  You have no use for it, unless you maintain missiles or rockets.  What you want is Liquid Wrench, Kroil, PB Blaster or if your country has an indigenous penetrating oil that local mechanics swear by, use that.  Penetrating oil is not rocket science.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - having used WD-40 for decades, and can't remember ever being let down by it, I'll carry on using it - but not for polishing my missile. Quite like snake oil too.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Why are you wasting time with (double!) links to an article that in no way has anything to do with your inaccurate assertion? It was not designed to "polish the Atlas missile", it was designed as a rust-prevention solvent and degreaser for use in the aerospace industry by Norm Larsen, and Convair, an aerospace contractor, first used WD-40 to protect the outer skin of the Atlas Missile from rust and corrosion - not to "polish" it. Saying something used on missiles is only suitable for use on missiles shows a lack of understanding of many materials in common use today.

Comment: I usually just replace the entire bib. It's easy, and not really expensive. Just requires a new valve, some silicone tape, and a couple of wrenches or pliers. But perhaps the really old ones are better quality than new ones, and worth fixing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the name of that top part, but this image from [The Fixit Zone](https://thefixitzone.blogspot.com/2014/04/replace-valve-packing-in-hose-bibb.html) calls it a "bonnet nut".  That could be a regional name.

[image: Hose bib diagram]

In a very traditional hose bib like yours, there are two ways for it to leak.  It can leak out of the hose connection if the internal washer is worn out, or it can leak out of the handle if the "packing" is worn.  For valves with larger bodies, you sometimes find fabric reenforced washers to seal the handle rather than packing, but small valves like yours use packing quite often.

The packing is basically a rubberish rope type material that you wind around the shaft and pack it into that area.  They have modern packing made from a teflon material.  [Sample listing on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FPAO2Y), but its a common repair item you should find in any store that sells plumbing supplies.

You would remove the handle (that screw can be a challenge) and then remove the "bonnet nut" to access the packing.  The valve will not leak as long as it is turned off, so you should be able to make the repair with the main water valve to the house still on.  If you want to do some preventative maintenance, you can go ahead and turn the water off, take the stem completely out and replace the internal washer as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the whole faucet, do a computer search for a 5/8" OD outside compression hose faucet. Arrowhead brass & plumbing has a model #254CCLF that should do the trick. You may find a replacement at a plumbing store or large hardware store. If you do not want to replace it , rebuild it as the other guys have written.